# Utility of "belongsTo" in manyToMany collection

Tags: grails

can any one explain to me what's the utility of belongsTo in a ManyToMany relationship? for a OneToOne relationship it's obvious : if a record from the "OneToMany" side (the master table) is  deleted the corresponding "ManyToOne" (the child table) are [CASCADE] deleted as well, but we can't apply the same thing in the case of ManyToMany relationShip since one child record may belongs to many records in the master table, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like with a one-to-many, adding items to the one side involves calling the `addTo*()` method. The one side is responsible for managing the collection. It provides the means to add/remove items.

It is no different for a many-to-many; a side must manage the collection. The difference is that GORM/Hibernate has no way of knowing which side to use; either side could technically do it, but only one can. So you must decide by using `belongsTo`. That's why the Grails documentation says one side must *own* the relationship. In short, it's a Hibernate thing.

Comment: Thank you, but when there is a relationship class (=the manyToMany becomes two oneToMany), there is no need to belongsTo right?

Comment: Correct. If you go that route as far as GORM is concerned you've got two one to many associations. It won't see it as a many to many.